# How to sum two columns if one column might have two different variables which would call for a different calculation

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, sum

I need to create a `SUM()` column (summing two columns), the issue I'm having in the second column might have a result which needs to multiply the first column or it might have a result which needs to be added to the result in the first column.

Example

First Column (Estimated Costs)

```
50,000
100,000
5,000
```

Second Column (contingency amounts)

```
5%
10,000
10%
5,000
```

The first column will always have numbers. The second column will either have a percentage or an amount. I need to create a formula to sum either possibility. Is this possible or do I need to create two different sum columns for either scenario?

I tried using an `OR` statement with the `SUM()` formula but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Will the percentage always be 100% or less? And will the amount always be greater than 1?

Comment: ^ To add to my previous comment, trying to find some criterion that will allow you to use `SUMIF`.

Comment: Yeah, the percentage will most likely always be under 20%. It is the contingency amount for marketing projects so just enough small percentage of the budget to account for any unexpected costs.

Comment: Then use `SUMIF` with `>1` as the criterion to sum the amounts. What do you need to do with the percentages? I.e. what should the expected result of your sample data be?

Comment: Do u want to include the % also in your Sum or Needs to be excluded? Could you please elaborate clearly? Because you have mentioned like -  "second column might have a result which needs to multiply the first column or it might have a result which needs to be added to the result in the first column"

Comment: Hey @regiz. I don't want to include the % in the sum column, just the total estimated cost with the contingency amount included. I would need either the estimated cost (column A) to be added to the contingency amount ( column B) in the sum column or if the contingency is a percentage, then I need the contingency percentage multiplied by the estimated cost and then added to the estimated cost to get the total estimated cost of the project. I apologize for not being clearer at first.

Comment: Hey @BigBen, the expected result is total expected costs including the contingency amount. This contingency amount can be an amount (in which case the cell with the estimated cost would simply be added to the cell with the contingency amount) or it can be a percentage (in which case I would need to multiply the estimated cost cell by the cell containing the contingency percentage and then add the result to the estimated cost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you're providing the cotingency cost of the estimate on 2 different ways as a percentage of the estimate or as a lumpsum amount to be added to the estimate.

You should use IF() to differentiate the two operations you have to apply. As the two types of values are very different on the contingency column the @BigBen suggestion of Value>1 should work perfectly well as you won't be adding less than $1 buck as a contingency. Therefore the formula will be:

```
=IF(B1>1,A1+B1,A1*(1+B1))
```

Column A is Estimated Costs, Column B is Contingency.

Comment: Thanks, Kaiser. The only thing is that the second part of the formula needs to be added to the estimated cost (value in column a) after the contingency percentage is multiplied by the estimated cost (A1*B1). A1+B1 would be the estimated cost plus the contingency amount. However, if the contingency amount is based on a percentage instead of an amount, then A1*B1 would give the contingency amount as a result. What I need in the second part of this formula (A1*B1 part) is the contingency percentage (such as 5%) times the estimated cost and then added to the estimated cost.

Comment: @CTEAGUE212: Got it! See updated formula now addressing the issue.